# getWritableDatabase() never been called

Tags: android, android-studio

Briefly, this is my class

```
public class sqlite extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public SQLiteDatabase db;
    public sqlite(Context context , String db_name , int db_version){
    super(context, db_name, null, db_version, null);
    try{this.db=getWritableDatabase();}catch(Exception e){this.db=getReadableDatabase();}
     }
```

when I call new `sqlite(*****);` the functions `getWritableDatabase()` and `getReadableDatabase()` always cause an error (NullPointerException on a null object reference) so what is the proper reference that I must call to implement these functions successfully?

***Edit*:**  I found a solution , but iam still wounder why the above code not work?
the solution is to remove getWritableDatabase() from sqlite (extends SQLiteOpenHelper) constructor to the operation method it self i.e: directly before CRUD methods ,
I don't know why it fails if called from the constructor

Comment: Where are you using the `db` variable? I think it's better to first instantiate your `sqlite` (why lower-case name for a class?) object and then use its reference to get WritableDatabase.

Comment: @Sherif Eldeeb Why do you want it to call in constructor? and from where you fetching your db tables , from assets or through code? so that i can provide you a solution for same.

Comment: @Nisarg  from SyncAdaptor class

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla , I use db from any other class ,
also I want to call getWritableDatabase() automaticcly without calling it from aother classes

Comment: Please include the class/code where you use this - you have to remove the call from your constructor - but it's difficult to advise how to do this without seeing that part of the code.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla , I intend to use this class from any other service ,
for example MainActivity or other background services 

sqlite db=new sqlite(***);

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the call to `getWritableDatabase` from the constructor. Instead, whenever you want to use the database-helper, you can simply call the instance of your `sqlite` class (which I strongly recommend you rename to something meaningful - following appropriate naming convention for Java classes).

```
//Here is an example (using this from an Activity or some other class):
//pass appropriate values for the arguments...
sqlite myDatabaseHelper = new sqlite(context, db_name, db_version);
//here you can get the writable-database object
SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = myDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
//from here you can perform your database operations - like querying/inserting values, etc
```

Comment: I want an idea to call getWritableDatabase() inside the constructor , or within the class sqlite itself , i.e the user not have to call this function by himself 

also what is the problem with calling getWritableDatabase() inside the constructor